# Meteor deploy on heroku buildpack issue

Tags: heroku, meteor, buildpack

I am trying to deploy a Meteor app on Heroku, but I keep getting the error:

`!     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
      to use for this application automatically.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks`

The link the error provides has a list of buildpacks, but I'm not sure how to install them. Can someone help? I'm on Meteor version 1.1.0.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a viable Meteor buildpack? This links to a pretty well-used one: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor

Just follow the instructions and you should be all set.

Comment: That contains instructions for the command line, whereas I am using the Heroku web app to deploy... Do you know where I can find instructions to deploy using the Heroku web app instead of command line?

Comment: How can you deploy using the web-app? It's basically the same steps, just do it on the command line or link a github repo with heroku.